# Cannot find Qt files when compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, qt4.7

I've a QT project that was initially designed both for UI as well as creating a server for the network. However, now I only need the network part of it to integrate with another UI implementation.

I stripped out the files and main function and compile the project as a library. All goes well.

However, when I try to include a header file from this project into another project, I get compile time errors like these (for the project that calls header files from QT project):

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QObject': No such file or directory
```

Both projects are part of the same VS2008 solution. I think I'm missing something, but cannot put my hands on it... Please help, thnx!

Comment: Project that compiles uses in its files relative path to Qt headers, the other project is located in a different directory than the one that compiles?

Comment: The path is not relative. Its included using `#include <QObject>` etc. and this project compiles into a .lib file. Am wondering if I wud have to set all the QT paths (both for includes and dlls, or just dlls, or...) for the other project as well?

Comment: Well, then it seems that the project that compiles has path to the Qt headers added to its path variable. The second project does not.

Comment: I tried to supply the path and though the above error disappeared, I had new errors like these: `c:\qt\qt4.7.3\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/global/qnamespace.h(1256) : error C2332: 'enum' : missing tag name`... however, what am unable to understand is that since the 1st project is already compiled to a .lib why the files from that project cause error?

Comment: Seems like I'm missing some basic know-how of Visual studio here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, is all fixed. Thanks @Petr-Budnik for the suggestions. Here is what I did...

1. Set the environment values (under Config properties->debugging) to update the path (this is how it was done in QT project). This value was setting path to include QTBin folder (which I suspect has any use)
2. Copied all the Preprocessor definitions from QT project to the main project
3. Update the include paths
4. Add QT .lib files in additional dependencies when stuck with Linking errors.

And an important (though weird) fix during compiling... I had to move the call to include this Qt project file to the top of my ".h" due to some weird QT compile time errors from file qnamespace.h and qmetatype.h (Thanks to the [tip from comment 2](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=587715))