# Qt headers not in Include path while building Qt application on Windows from command line

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qmake

I'm trying to build statically linked Qt application on Windows from command line using `qmake` and `jom`.

I've already built static version of Qt successfully. The source code is in `C:\Temp\qt\src`, binaries are in `C:\Temp\qt\build\x86_64`. I'm using the following `qmake` binary: `C:\Temp\qt\build\x86_64\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe`.

While building the application it seems that standard Qt include files cannot be found:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QObject': No such file or directory
```

This is my build script:

```
@echo off
set QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2013
set VCVARS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat
set QTDIR=C:\Temp\qt\
set PATH=%QTDIR%\bin;%QTDIR%\build\x86_64\qtbase\bin;%PATH%

call "%VCVARS%" x86_amd64
qmake -makefile -Wall "CONFIG=release" Project.pro
jom
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886743/cannot-find-qt-files-when-compiling

Comment: @svlasov It's not a duplicate in my opinion. That question deals with visual studio solution settings and while I indeed use VC++ compiler I am building with qmake/jom and not a VS solution file. That answer is of little use to me.